# Getting error "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected XXX row(s)" while updating a record when table has trigger on it

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having a table with "After Update Trigger". When I am trying to update a record, I am getting the `Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected XXX row(s)` error.
Below code will throws the error.

```
var entity = await _repositoryUser.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
entity.StatusId = 4;
_repositoryUser.Update(entity);
await _repositoryUser.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But when I disable the trigger and execute the code, it works. Example

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(_context.Database, "DISABLE TRIGGER triggerName ON [dbo].[User];");
await _repositoryUser.SaveChangesAsync();
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(_context.Database, "ENABLE TRIGGER triggerName ON [dbo].[User];");
```

Questions:

1. Why `EntityFrameworkCore` has this limitation?
2. Is there any better approach to avoid disabling the trigger every time updating an entity?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I see an emoji, I downvote.

Comment: Which exactly version of EF are you using? Which RDBMS are you using? EF7 has breaking changes: [SQL Server tables with triggers or certain computed columns now require special EF Core configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#sqlserver-tables-with-triggers)

Comment: Removed emojis, thanks.
I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore-5.0.11.

Comment: Interesting reading for you [Allow opt-out of optimistic concurrency/rows affected check in the model](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10443)

Comment: I have gone through it @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Looks like migrating EFCore to 7.x is the only option.

Comment: @JitanGupta. not sure that updating to EF Core 7 will help. Issue is still not closed.

Comment: Agree @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I might need to do a POC before coming to any conclusion.

Comment: With EF Core 7 you can define update method via Stored Procedure, it may fix your problem.